# Run of Mutiple fastq files for fastqc analysis

Tags: bash, shell, fastq, google-genomics

I would run the following code for multiple fastq files in a folder. In a folder I have different fastq files; first I have to read one file and perform the required operations by activating the miniconda , then store results in a separate file. fastq and then read second file, perform the same operations and save results in new 2nd file.fastq using the bash script and python script

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory of with mutiple fastq files#
FILES= " /home/folder/sample"

for f in $ FILES

do 
  conda activate FAST_qc    # actibvating the miniconda
  echo "Process the file $f
  mkdir "$f"                # making directory
  fastqc "$f"               # task to perform
done
```

Comment: Maybe you could click [edit], select your code with the mouse and click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format it as code

Comment: What is your question? Also, there’s a typo in your script: it should be `$FILES`, not `$ FILES`.

Comment: Try to solve all the issues that shellcheck will throw at you, and the you can try stating a question.